# Why Eclipse shows syntax coloring wrong?

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting

I have the eclipse juno service release 1 with CFeclipse.
I want to post an image to show you my problem, but because i'm a new user i can't. So i try to explain..

The syntax coloring preferences are set, so that text is black and expressions in quotes are blue. When i use single quotes, then after the closing quote all of the following code is blue. The code is correct, i tried it in dreamweaver, and all of the code was highlighted fine.
Someone has an answer?

Comment: The same issue at [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/cfeclipse-users/syntax$20cfscript/cfeclipse-users/_d6YBxr3pDA/oiflve6efPgJ)

Answer (score -1):

Colors are customizable:

Window > Preference > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts

Comment: Thanks, but i know where i can set the preferences for colors and fonts. But the codehighlighting is going crazy, that has nothing to do with the general preferences i think. The same issue at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/cfeclipse-users/syntax$20cfscript/cfeclipse-users/_d6YBxr3pDA/oiflve6efPgJ

Comment: Sometimes this is related with other plugins installed mixing the way eclipse understand each code file. OR its just a bug in the related version.

Comment: I don't think that it's a bug in the related version, but that something is wrong with the CFeclipse plugin, because the problem appears just within <cfscript></cfscript>. But then i'm really surprised, that nobody has noticed the problem and fixed it.. i will try several changes in the preferences.. anybody knows the answer?

Comment: i tried different things and noticed, that the problem only appears:
1. within cfscript
2. when a closing html-tag is followed by a single quote